# File server on Linux

Tags: linux, file-upload, web-hosting

How to set-up an ubuntu machine as a file server? I already saw the steps to host a page using ubuntu(with apache2) but I want to be able to save my file and give the direct link of the file for downloading. Any ideas?
Or is there any other easy way to allow hosting of a file?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a real question. We don't know what is the best for you and your environment (in part because you didn't tell us anything about that). Please make your question more specific. Also check the FAQ about the kind of questions that are suitable here.

Comment: @Holder: OOps. Guess I have to re-word it. I wanted to know how to build a file server. Anything else is "not-useful" information. I shall edit my question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to serve files for testing then

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer &
```

Will make the current directory available as `http://localhost:8000/whatever`.  Obviously this isn't secure, but if you just want to share files over a network you control (you can replace localhost with the name of the machine) then it's a quick way to do it.

Comment: I have a system in the same subnet and which can do a ping on it too but this system is unable to connect(it keeps waiting to connect) to this http://localIP:8000/...  Is there a fix?

Comment: Here is the link to the tutorial:http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python

Comment: @user489152 Are you sure that it is running without error on the remote host?

Comment: I tried to change IP address to my local subnet IP in BaseHTTPServer.py. But although I see that it is beeing hosted from this IP, I still cannot call it from the browser. It always says waiting to connect :(